# AutoMapper generic map method does not map enum values

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I have a generic mapper function for mapping between View models and Domain models. For some reason, it does not map Enum values.

```
public TDomainModel MapToDomainModel<TViewModel, TDomainModel>(TViewModel viewModel)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<TViewModel, TDomainModel>();
    TDomainModel result = Mapper.Map<TViewModel, TDomainModel>(viewModel);
    return result;
}

public TViewModel MapToViewModel<TDomainModel, TViewModel>(TDomainModel domainModel)
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<TDomainModel, TViewModel>();
    TViewModel result = Mapper.Map<TDomainModel, TViewModel>(domainModel);
    return result;
}
```

I need to map enum values to integers when mapping from view model to domain model. And map from integers to enum values when mapping from domain models to view models.

It would be great if the solution is flexible enough to convert from nullable enums to more types (short, byte etc) and vice versa.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: I had to change all enums to lookup tables and use conventional methods to read / write. I would be interested if someone finds a solution.

Comment: I'm working on a solution as we speak. If I manage to solve it in a neat way I will get back to you.

Comment: @MagnusBackeus That would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

using autofac mapper?

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<TViewModel, TDomainModel>()
                 .ForMember(dest => dest.enumfield, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => (EnumFieldEnum)src.EnumField))               
                 .ReverseMap();
});


mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

...`

```
var yy= mapper.Map<TDomainModel>(xx);
```